# TYPO3 7.6.10: How to extend the felogin extension?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I tried to extend the core extension **`felogin`** with an extra extension called "feloginextended".

I want to add the **`first_name`** and the **`last_name`** property of the current user into my logout formular.

This is my **overridden template** (only the logout part):

```
<!--###TEMPLATE_LOGOUT###-->
<form class="login-form" action="###ACTION_URI###" target="_top" method="post">
    <div>
        <div class="user">###FIRSTNAME### ###LASTNAME###</div>
        <a class="page-link-button" href="http://tf.lightblue.eu/index.php?id=14">Meine Siegel</a>
        <a class="page-link-button" href="http://tf.lightblue.eu/index.php?id=15">Mein Account</a>
        <input class="form-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout" />
     </div>

    <div class="felogin-hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="logintype" value="logout" />
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="###STORAGE_PID###" />
        <input type="hidden" name="###PREFIXID###[noredirect]" value="###NOREDIRECT###" />
    </div>
</form>
<!--###TEMPLATE_LOGOUT###-->
```

Then I added the Controller **`Classes\Xclass\FrontendLoginController`** to my extension.

I copied the original file and add some changes in the showLogout function, to set the markers:

```
 <?php
 namespace Typo3\feloginextended\Xclass;

 use \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

 /**
  * Plugin 'Website User Login' for the 'felogin' extension.
  */
 class FrontendLoginController extends AbstractPlugin
 {

 /**
 * Shows logout form
 *
 * @return string The content.
 */
protected function showLogout()
{
    $subpart = $this->cObj->getSubpart($this->template, '###TEMPLATE_LOGOUT###');
    $subpartArray = ($linkpartArray = array());
    $markerArray['###STATUS_HEADER###'] = $this->getDisplayText('status_header', $this->conf['logoutHeader_stdWrap.']);
    $markerArray['###STATUS_MESSAGE###'] = $this->getDisplayText('status_message', $this->conf['logoutMessage_stdWrap.']);
    $this->cObj->stdWrap($this->flexFormValue('message', 's_status'), $this->conf['logoutMessage_stdWrap.']);
    $markerArray['###LEGEND###'] = $this->pi_getLL('logout', '', true);
    $markerArray['###ACTION_URI###'] = $this->getPageLink('', array(), true);
    $markerArray['###LOGOUT_LABEL###'] = $this->pi_getLL('logout', '', true);
    $markerArray['###NAME###'] = htmlspecialchars($this->frontendController->fe_user->user['name']);
    $markerArray['###STORAGE_PID###'] = $this->spid;
    $markerArray['###USERNAME###'] = htmlspecialchars($this->frontendController->fe_user->user['username']);
    $markerArray['###USERNAME_LABEL###'] = $this->pi_getLL('username', '', true);
    $markerArray['###NOREDIRECT###'] = $this->noRedirect ? '1' : '0';
    $markerArray['###PREFIXID###'] = $this->prefixId;
    // my custom changes-----------------------------------
    $markerArray['###FIRSTNAME###'] = htmlspecialchars($this->frontendController->fe_user->user['first_name']);
    $markerArray['###LASTNAME###'] = htmlspecialchars($this->frontendController->fe_user->user['last_name']);
    //------------------------------------------------------
    $markerArray = array_merge($markerArray, $this->getUserFieldMarkers());
    if ($this->redirectUrl) {
        // Use redirectUrl for action tag because of possible access restricted pages
        $markerArray['###ACTION_URI###'] = htmlspecialchars($this->redirectUrl);
        $this->redirectUrl = '';
    }
    return $this->cObj->substituteMarkerArrayCached($subpart, $markerArray, $subpartArray, $linkpartArray);
}
}
```

Then I register my template in the **`ext_typoscript_setup.txt`** file:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    templateFile = EXT:feloginextended/Resources/Private/Templates/FrontendLogin.html
}
```

And my final step was the registration of the controller in the **`ext_localconf.php`**:

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die('Access denied.');
}

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\Controller\\FrontendLoginController'] = array(
    'className' => 'Typo3\\Feloginextended\\Xclass\\FrontendLoginController',
);
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['tx_felogin_pi1'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\Controller\\FrontendLoginController'];
```

If add this changes into the original files of the felogin extension, then I have a solution.

But this way is very dirty and in the future I can't update the felogin extension easily.

I found this "solution": https://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/202500/ 
But it don't work for me.

Have anyone an idea or have an other way to bring the first and the last name of the current user to the logout formular?

**EDIT:**
I get everytime a http error 500!

Thanks Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. You can just add the markers `###FEUSER_FIRST_NAME###` and `###FEUSER_LAST_NAME###` to your template and they will be replaced by the right values. This schema is general and can be used on all fields of the user:

`###FEUSER_{DB field in uppercase}###`. Note that the fields are used with underscores and not the lower camelcase.

This works in TYPO3 6.x and the code looks the same in 7.6 so it should work too.

Comment: Omg this is so easy. Thanks a lot

Comment: Works in TYPO3 8 like a charm, too! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that your extension `EXT:feloginextended` is installed and you cleared all caches including the full cache clear provided by the install tool, you have done everything correct. Delete also the directory `/typo3temp/autoload` completely.

The only thing which may be wrong is the loading order of the extensions, which is important in case you define your TS-Setup inside the file `ext_typoscript_setup.txt`.
In this case you must force your extension to be loaded after the original EXT:felogin extension. And the only way to assure that is to add the extension felogin to the list of "suggests" constraint setting inside `EXT:feloginextended/ext_emconf.php`.
Then you must fully deinstall your extension and install it again.

```
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    [...]
    'constraints' => array(
        [...]
        'suggests' => array(
           'felogin' => '7.6.0-7.6.99'
        ),
    )
);
```

To continue the answer after your error 500 information.
This must be a class loader problem as well, the fact that you are seeing 500 error is caused by PHP or TYPO3 error reporting configuration.

Anyway I copied your approach as follows:

EXT:my_extension/ext_localconf.php

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\CMS\Felogin\Controller\FrontendLoginController'] = array(
    'className' => 'Typo3\Feloginextended\Xclass\FrontendLoginController',
);
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['tx_felogin_pi1'] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Felogin\\Controller\\FrontendLoginController'];
```

EXT:my_extension/ext_typoscript_setup.txt

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    templateFile = EXT:my_extension/FrontendLogin.html
}
```

EXT:my_extension/Classes/FrontendLoginController.php

```
<?php
namespace Typo3\Feloginextended\Xclass;

use TYPO3\CMS\Felogin\Controller\FrontendLoginController as BaseFrontendLoginController;

/**
 * Plugin 'Website User Login' for the 'felogin' extension.
 */
class FrontendLoginController extends BaseFrontendLoginController
{

    /**
     * Shows login form
     *
     * @return string The content.
     */
    protected function showLogin()
    {

        $subpart = $this->cObj->getSubpart($this->template, '###TEMPLATE_LOGIN###');
        $subpartArray = ($linkpartArray = array());
        $markerArray['###MY_MARKER###'] = 'My new login';
        return $this->cObj->substituteMarkerArrayCached($subpart, $markerArray, $subpartArray, $linkpartArray);
    }
    }
```

EXT:my_extension/FrontendLogin.html

```
[...]

<!--###TEMPLATE_LOGIN###-->

###MY_MARKER###

<!--###TEMPLATE_LOGIN###-->

<!--###TEMPLATE_LOGOUT###-->

My New Logout

<!--###TEMPLATE_LOGOUT###-->

[...]
```

The result is totally correct instead of the login form I see 'My New Login', so everything is working for me.

The solution for you is:

1) You have a typo in the namespace. It must be `namespace Typo3\**F**eloginextended\Xclass;` instead of `namespace Typo3\**f**eloginextended\Xclass;`

2) You must inherit from `TYPO3\CMS\Felogin\Controller\FrontendLoginController`

**Do not forget to clear typo3temp/Cache/* and typo3temp/autoload/*** !

Comment: Thx for your answer, but this is unfortunately not the solution. I still get a http error 500. In my opinion the controller can't be loaded, but why?

Comment: Ah, you did not mention any 500 problems loading the controller :-) It sounded like your TypoScript with custom template has no effect. PLease edit your question and post the full content of your XCLASS. See also my edited answer with added tip to delete typo3temp/autoload directory.

Comment: `/typo3temp/autoload` is cleared automatically if you deactive or activate an extension. So no need to delete it by hand.

Comment: May be true Bernd, but imagine you develop an extension as Felix does, and you add a XCLASS after the extension has been installed.
However, deleting it by hand does not harm as standard procedure in case of class loader problems and personally it saved my day many times in the past.

Comment: It is no autoload error, because by a autoload error typo3 throw a exception and no http error 500

Comment: Felix, please post the full content of your XCLASS.

Comment: I can't post the whole code, because to much lines. The limit is 30000 characters. Have a look in the original code from the felogin extension:
"TYPO3\sysext\felogin\Classes\Controller\FrontendLoginController"

Comment: OK, but you mentioned, that you modified the showLogout() method only, so you do not need to copy all the other methods from tne original class in the first place, You must inherit from the the original class though.
Having done that, post the entire, small file. I am interested in the namespace declaration etc.

Comment: See my extended answer

Comment: Felix, Did you check if your errors are gone after cleaning the typo in namespace and inheriting from the correct class?

Comment: I will give Feedback if I have checked your solution. Probably next Tuesday :)

Comment: So I tested your code, but still get the same error