# TYPO3 felogin: remove legend

Tags: typo3, felogin

Simple question: how can I remove the html `<legend>` tag from my felogin content elements? I've read the felogin documentation but I still don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, copy the template to your own theme extension (or fileadmin folder). 
Then, remove all the markup that you don't need.

Use this TypoScript to let your system know where to find the new felogin template:

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile = EXT:yourtheme/Resources/Private/Extensions/felogin/FrontendLogin.html
```

(Change the path to your fileadmin, if you save the template file there.)

HTH!

Comment: okay I guess I'm gonna have to read more tutorials about typo3. I have no idea how to program / set up my own extension.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at Markus Klein's

https://bitbucket.org/reelworx/rx-typo3-sitesetup

Find me at Slack: @rowild for further questions!

Comment: Fiddling with my little local test server I'm slowly understanding how things work, I don't think I need more help here :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: hi again, a new question arises: I know that I could change the template and remove the "legend" tags. However inside these legend tags there's a marker ###LEGEND###. At some point something / somewhere (where? which script?) will try to fill that ###LEGEND### marker and maybe throw an error since it's not there anymore. Where is the logic implemented that fills the markers? I guess I have to touch that too, if I modify the template?

Comment: To my knowledge felogin behaves according to TYPO3's old templating system using the "route"-markers. They are handled in a class file of the extension. Have a look at typo3/sysext/felogin/Classes/Controller/FrontendLoginController.php, search for "###LEGEND" and see what it does.
I didn't test it (did you?) whether ommitting/deleting the marker causes an error. But if so, you might want to look into Xclass-ing the felogin classes. I saw a bit of a discussion going on here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259950/typo3-7-6-10-how-to-extend-the-felogin-extension. HTH!

Comment: I just read in the Slack typo3-cms-dev channel that they are working on an improved felogin with fluid templates for TYPO3 v9. That's awesome!!!
In the meantime you could check hairu as an alternative:
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/hairu/

Comment: I've had a little bit of trouble with my local install, it didn't show the content elements that I created in the backend (such as felogin form). But I got that fixed now, so by now I was able to test the template changes: if you remove the <legend> tags he doesn't complain! (as you've probably suspected since you've asked for a test) The legend just disappears and he apparently doesn't try to fill the ###LEGEND### marker (which resides inside the legend tags). However I'm still curious about how things work in the background. But I'll find out myself, problem is solved, thanks once again :)

Comment: Things happen in typo3_src/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Service/MarkerBasedTemplateService.php. 
Q: are you new to TYPO3? Or do you have to work with old versions of TYPO3? Because the marker-based template system is kind of old and seems to be kept mainly for backwards compatibility and some not-yet-reworked system ext (like felogin). If you can manage to use a substitute ext based on Fluid, I'd rather recommend getting your head around that... ;-)

Comment: Yes, I am new to typo3 (been working with django before) and yes, I have to work with a website which is running on a very old version :-) (6.x ...)